# DocBook to PDF with Cooperate Identity (Linux)

Tags: pdf, xslt, centos, docbook, dblatex

We have a Wiki-Page. Where we document our work and projects. From this page you can download the articles in different formats, like Text-File, HTML-File or as DocBook.

Now I need to transform the DocBook into a PDF. This part works, I did it with dblatex.

```
dblatex doc.xml
```

But the PDF-Document needs our Cooperate Identity (Headline & Foot-line). I have no idea how to do that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a lot of work with the DocBook XSLT stylesheets that produce Formatting Objects (FO). That's a different way to publish PDF from DocBook source.

There is an excellent set of documentation that explains how to customize PDF output if you're using the FO workflow. Here's the section about that:

http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/PrintHeaders.html

Learning how to customize the dblatex conversion might be a great choice. I have never used it so I'm offering the FO conversion as an alternative.

Good luck!